# Primefaces UI component need to get value from jQuery instead of getting it from the server(managed bean)

Tags: jquery, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I want to know if there is way that primefaces UI can use the value from jQuery. For example, i have placed array of values into 'imgArray' now i want to display it in p:datalist.

**jQuery**

```
$.getJSON("http://xxxx?url="+ url,function(data){
    var imageArray=[];
    imageArray=data.images;
      $("formId:dataTable).html(imageArray);
```

**UI**

```
<p:datalist id="dataTable" value= />
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe that this is not possible. The JSF page is rendered server side. The `values` must refer to an element collection.

Use a Java based solution to create a collection of the supplied JSON.

Comment: You can please elobrate the last line you mentioned

Comment: In a backing bean you can use one of several solutions (JAX-RS, GSon,etc.) to transform the JSON to usable Java classes.

Comment: Using "@nickname" doesn't work if the other hasn't commented on the post before.